# Field access costs and constant folding in JMH benchmark

Tags: java, performance, jmh

I'm running the following benchmark on Java 17:

```java
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(jvmArgsAppend = {"-Xms2g", "-Xmx2g"})
public class ValueOfBenchmark {
    private final int value = 12345;

    @Benchmark
    public String concat() {
        return "" + value;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String valueOf() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

After compilation I have this bytecode

```
  public concat()Ljava/lang/String;
  @Lorg/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Benchmark;()
   L0
    LINENUMBER 21 L0
    LDC "12345"
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/tsypanov/ovn/ValueOfBenchmark; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x1
  public valueOf()Ljava/lang/String;
  @Lorg/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Benchmark;()
   L0
    LINENUMBER 26 L0
    SIPUSH 12345
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/String;
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/tsypanov/ovn/ValueOfBenchmark; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

Here I conclude that javac constant-folded the value of accessed field at compile time. In `concat` method it went even further and predicted eventual value to be returned from the method, but failed to do the same for `valueOf()` and as a result constant value of `12345` is pushed onto the stack with subsequent call to `String.valueOf()`.

This benchmark gives the following results:

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
ValueOfBenchmark.concat   avgt   40  1,665 ± 0,006  ns/op
ValueOfBenchmark.valueOf  avgt   40  4,475 ± 0,217  ns/op
```

Then I remove `final` from `value` field declaration and recompile the benchmark:

```
public concat()Ljava/lang/String;
@Lorg/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Benchmark;()
 L0
  LINENUMBER 21 L0
  ALOAD 0
  GETFIELD com/tsypanov/ovn/ValueOfBenchmark.value : I
  INVOKEDYNAMIC makeConcatWithConstants(I)Ljava/lang/String; [
    // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
    java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    // arguments:
    "\u0001"
  ]
  ARETURN
 L1
  LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/tsypanov/ovn/ValueOfBenchmark; L0 L1 0
  MAXSTACK = 1
  MAXLOCALS = 1

// access flags 0x1
public valueOf()Ljava/lang/String;
@Lorg/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Benchmark;()
 L0
  LINENUMBER 26 L0
  ALOAD 0
  GETFIELD com/tsypanov/ovn/ValueOfBenchmark.value : I
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/String;
  ARETURN
 L1
  LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/tsypanov/ovn/ValueOfBenchmark; L0 L1 0
  MAXSTACK = 1
  MAXLOCALS = 1
```

Now we have `invokedynamic` for `concat()` method, but `valueOf()` remained basically the same, the only difference is that int value is read from the field. This however brought significant regression of results:

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
ValueOfBenchmark.concat   avgt   40   9,829 ± 0,059  ns/op
ValueOfBenchmark.valueOf  avgt   40  10,238 ± 0,463  ns/op
```

For sure I expected this for `concat()` method as now we do concat two values into one String.

But what puzzles me is the regression of `valueOf()` method.

I assume that the costs of calling `String.valueOf()` within benchmark method remained the same, so why does the field access become so expensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that the costs of calling String.valueOf() within benchmark method remained the same

It is not. In the first case, the method argument is constant, so JIT can apply the [Constant Propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) optimization.

Consider a very simplified example:

```java
static char getLastDigit(int n) {
    return (char) ((n % 10) + '0');
}

char c1 = getLastDigit(123);

char c2 = getLastDigit(this.n);
```

When `getLastDigit` is called with a constant, there is no need to execute the actual division or addition - JIT may replace the entire call with `char c1 = '3';` It obviously can't do the same optimization with a variable.

Of course, `Integer.getChars` is more complex, but it still may skip some comparisons and arithmetic operations when called with a constant.